Why won't systemd run some of my scripts, but it will run others?
I've written a service file based on this old answer that runs a script whenever I wake my Ubuntu 24.04 Wayland PC from suspend. This is the logscript.sh script that's run:
#!/bin/bash
echo "script completed at $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" >> ~/logfile.txt

and this is the systemd my_user_script.service file:
[Unit]
Description=Run my_user_script
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/logscript.sh
#ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/launch-thunderbird.sh
#ExecStart=/bin/flatpak run org.mozilla.Thunderbird
User=my_user_name
Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

Everything works as expected. Each time I wake from suspend a new event is logged. However, when I comment out my logscript.sh line and instead try to run my launch-thunderbird.sh line the service file doesn't appear to work anymore.
...
#ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/logscript.sh
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/launch-thunderbird.sh
#ExecStart=/bin/flatpak run org.mozilla.Thunderbird
...

My launch-thunderbird.sh is simply:
#!/bin/bash
flatpak run org.mozilla.Thunderbird 

Why can a systemd service file run my logscript.sh script but it can't run my launch-thunderbird.sh script? I also tried commenting out the first two ExecStart=... and uncommenting the ExecStart=/bin/flatpak run org.mozilla.Thunderbird line but that fails to launch Thunderbird upon wake-from-suspend as well.
In case you're wondering I can run the launch-thunderbird.sh script from the terminal and it launches Thunderbird. It's got 755 permissions.

It's almost certainly the same reason as for Using notify-send with cron

In that solution they mention that this works for cron in an Ubuntu Wayland session: * * * * *  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) notify-send Hey "this is dog!". So how do I roll that into my systemd service file? Or scripts?

how do you know that launch-thunderbird.sh is not run?

@jophuh if that would solve your problem, then. put export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) at the top of your script.

You should be able to see what's wrong with systemctl status your_service or journalctl -b -u your_service? For one you haven't included the XAUTHORITY env var, assuming the DISPLAY is correct. (You mentioned Wayland though.) (Either way, while there is or is no better way, running a GUI application program with a systemd system service is still more or less a quirky thing to do.)

The script actually is running as jsotola thought. It's just not launching the flatpak. I tried muru's suggestion but it didn't work. I need to create a new different question.

It turns out my question was wrong, and systemd was actually running the script. It just wasn't executing it in the way I thought it "should". In other words the script wasn't launching my flatpak. I'm not exactly sure what is not happening, or why. I'll have to create a new question addressing this.

I think you should really just delete this whole post instead of "answering" it.

@Tom Yan yeah I think that's a good idea, unfortunately I don't have enough stack points to delete my post. If you do feel free to delete it. I'm not sure exactly how this works.
